# will using git interfere with bixby IDE?

Tags: git, bixby, bixbystudio

I want to use git for version control of my bixby capsule folder. Is it safe?

I initiated a repository and checked it in.

Here is my .gitignore.

```
*training.bxb
.DS_Store
```

I want to know if it is safe to roll back to previous commits, etc. in a capsule that is also a git repository.

Comment: I am particularly concerned about the behind the scenes operation of the IDE which seems to do a lot of analysis of the capsule file structures - worried about files/metadata getting corrupted inadvertently, etc.

Comment: Make sure to use `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, and Git won't modify any file, leaving the IDE work with said files as intended.

Comment: FYI You need to track your training.bxb files

Answer (score 2):

It should not: [`rogerkibbe/bixby_bart_commuter`](https://github.com/rogerkibbe/bixby_bart_commuter) is an example of a Bixby Capsule

The [Quick start Guide](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/get-started/quick-start#create-your-capsule) for the IDE does mention:

> Download and extract the files in this sample capsule from our GitHub repository, or clone the repository before starting.
>
> Dice Sample Capsule GitHub repository: https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-dice/
>
> Once you have cloned or extracted the capsule, use File > Open Capsule to open the capsule

Answer (score 1):

Git is the recommended VCS to use with Bixby Developer Studio. The application monitors the file system and updates the application's internal state based on file system event handlers (e.g. `update | create | delete`).

One additional note about training, I see you are excluding `*training.bxb` files with the `.gitignore` file. Although (today) in Bixby Studio we do not reveal training files to the File Explorer or Editor, they are just like any other `*.bxb` file and essential to your capsule's source code. The Training UI provided by Bixby Developer Studio is just a fancy view of all those `*.training.bxb` files.

---

Disclaimer: I work on the Bixby Developer Studio engineering team

Comment: Incidentally, this is the section of the Training guide that made me concerned about saving training files:

Caution
Training files are not meant to be edited outside of Bixby Studio, and doing so can introduce syntax errors. If Bixby Studio reports an error, try removing the problematic training entry and re-entering it through the training editor.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training

Comment: @FredZimmerman A simple answer: Yes, it is safe to use GitHub. Yes, it is safe to add training files. Please let us know if you encountered an issue.